# Will Increasing AWS Elastic Beanstalk Instance Size or Increasing Load Balancers Help Reduce Random 502 Nginx Errors?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing, http-status-code-502

I recently added a CPU-intensive 20MB+ image decoding/parsing function to my Elastic Beanstalk application, and noticed that sometimes (~10% of the time) either calling the function itself, or subsequent, unrelated requests to the app result in a `502` error, from Nginx, not the app itself:

```
[09/Oct/2020:01:51:06 +0000] "GET /plaid/eoinfoinwfe HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit
```

My Elastic Beanstalk instance is a `t2.small` running a `Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.2.0` OS, and my load balancer looks like:

```
Listeners: 2
Load balancer type: application
Processes: 1
```

Would either switching to a bigger instance size or increasing processes of my Load Balancer help to mitigate the `502` errors that I'm seeing?

Comment: In an ideal scenerio, you would have dedicated worker environments for heavy processing. Your webservers shoudn't be doing this. But anyway, have you checked CPU or memory mettrics?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, I agree, but my partner decided to C-Type the C++ Library and bind it to Python in our webserver rather than set up a standalone Server. It seems like I hit on average 80% CPU utilization for about a 10 minute interval while I was testing the functionality (by myself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional info in the comments suggest that CPU utilization is high (80%). This is problematic because `t2.small` instances are **burstable** and have only **1 vCPU**. So once an EB instance is busy processing the images for long time not only you may consume all CPU so that other processes on the instance can't work efficiently, it may be also depleting its CPU credits, further impacting its performance.

You could try changing to t2.medium which has 2 vCPUs and setting it in [unlimited mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-unlimited-mode.html) to overcome its CPU credit limitations. But since your tasks are CPU intensive, maybe it would be better to switch from t2, which are general purpose instances, into C5 family which are **compute optimized**. This way you don't have to worry about any CPU credits, but obviously they cost more. For comparison `t2.small` has 1 CPU with a clock 2.5GHz, while `c5.large` has 2 CPUs with 3.4 GHz.

Comment: Switch to C5.large has made it so I don't see any more 502s from Nginx. Thanks!